# In .Net-MVC Url "\" converts to "/" automatically, How to prevent that?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, escaping

One of my route map is

```
BO/{businessObjectTypeId}/{*businessObjectId}
```

So, any url like `//localhost/BO/2/zs%5cbbal`, properly maps to the above route map. If you notice I am sending `zs\bbal` as the businessObjectId(used %5c to escape `\`).

Now the problem is when I get the businessObjectId in the specified action it is `zs/bbal`, instead of `zs\bbal`. I tried many other "Unsafe characters" and they seems to appear properly. It's just the `\` that converts itself to `/`.

Is it normal? Cannot we pass `\` as it is or by escaping it? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: One thing I noticed, it doesn't matter how many times you put "%5c" consecutively. It becomes single "/". So, zs%5c%5c%5cbbal is similar to zs%5cbbal. Strange.

Comment: How are you running the site? Is it with Casini or IIS? Which versions? Sometimes these make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try %5c%5c to escape (\\)?